# Formatting ChartLabels in BarChart. More than one subscript letter appear non-italic

Tags: charts, subscript

I want to plot a `BarChart` with quantities some of which are named with one subscript letter and some with two. The quantities with one subscript letter appear completely italic with the default setting but if I use two subscript letters the subscript letters appear non-italic:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, ChartLabels -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(A\), \(XY\)]\)", 
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(B\), \(X\)]\)", 
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(XZ\)]\)"}]
```

The minimal example above produces the following figure:

[image]

Is it possible to format the subscripts consistently italic or non-italic?

Comment: Add `BaseStyle -> MultiLetterItalics -> True` to get them all italic.

Comment: The meanwhile deleted comment that I should use symbols instead of strings was very helpful in combination with `MultiLetterItalics -> True`.